# Object created with python, disappear after any change on mesh, how to fix?

Tags: python

I create object from only vertex, when object is appear, i wanna for example make edges from vert, when i make it, it dissapier, in object mode i see only i make after for example one edge, if i switch to edit mode, i see full object

verts from file in code below https://pastebin.com/r8fbrHRg

code

```
import os
import bpy
import json

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Settings
name = 'Girl'

verts = []
faces = []
edges = []

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Add Object to Scene




with open('E:/Dev/PetProjects/PythonPetProjects/Resonance/src/resonance/output.txt', 'r') as vrs:
    verts = json.loads(vrs.read())


#with open('E:/Dev/PetProjects/PythonPetProjects/Resonance/src/resonance/output2.txt', 'r') as edgs:
#    edges = json.loads(edgs.read())


mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(name)
mesh.from_pydata(verts, edges, [])

obj = bpy.data.objects.new(name, mesh)
bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(obj)

bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
mesh.update()
```

video
https://youtu.be/a8TXQ8eUODY

Comment: I think Blender is supposed to work this way? If an object has faces, only the faces are shown. If an object has no faces, but only edges, only the edges are shown. If an object has no faces, and no edges, then the vertices are shown?